# Running Rails Application as root user on nginx

Tags: nginx, ruby-on-rails, root

My application(running on nginx) is unable to ssh into a remote machine, reason being that the client has has given ssh rights only to the root user on their server. While debugging this issue, I ran a command

```
'whoami'
```

from my application and the output was

```
'nobody'.
```

Can someone explain how can I run my application as the root user on nginx?

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't want to run your app as root user. What you need to do is to give your SSH login mechanism, whatever that might be, the username to login to on the remote machine. `nobody` is just used because you didn't state a name.

On the shell:

```
ssh user@hostname
```